# How to count values in a file

Tags: awk, sed

How to calculate the values as given:
The first column contains the Contig values

```
Contig
c_000000000002
c_000000000002
c_000000000002
c_000000000002
c_000000000003
c_000000000003
c_000000000003
c_000000000003
c_000000000008
c_000000000008
c_000000000013
c_000000000013
```

I want to count the values in the column and find the corresponding value for the contig. The "Contig" and "Count_of_Contig" should be separated by a tab.

```
Contig Count_of_contig
c_000000000002 2_1
c_000000000002 2_2
c_000000000002 2_3
c_000000000002 2_4
c_000000000003 3_1
c_000000000003 3_2
c_000000000003 3_3
c_000000000003 3_4
c_000000000008 8_1
c_000000000008 8_2
c_000000000013 13_1
c_000000000013 13_2
```

I would like to request a one-line linux command for this. Header is not nesessary to present in the output. It is just presented here to easily understand the output.

Comment: Please edit your post to indicate what you already tried and where you failed. That way you can avoid receiving answers that you already know won't work.

Comment: @Roland please edit your question and show _exactly_ what you ran and _exactly_ what the output was. We can't understand what the issue is in the comments.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Were these files ever opened in Windows?

Comment: Indeed. You are right terdon. The file was opened in Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy with `awk`:

```bash
awk -F _ -v OFS='\t' '
  NR == 1 {print $0, "Count_of_contig"; next}
  {print $0, 0+$2 "_" ++count[$0]}' < input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could come up with using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.7.0/)

```
$ mlr --pprint put '
    @n[$Contig] += 1; 
    $Count_of_contig = sub($Contig,"c_0*(.*)","\1_" . @n[$Contig])
  ' input
Contig         Count_of_contig
c_000000000002 2_1
c_000000000002 2_2
c_000000000002 2_3
c_000000000002 2_4
c_000000000003 3_1
c_000000000003 3_2
c_000000000003 3_3
c_000000000003 3_4
c_000000000008 8_1
c_000000000008 8_2
c_000000000013 13_1
c_000000000013 13_2
```

It's frustrating for a number of reasons:

1. there is [no ++ or --](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-dsl-differences/#no-or-), forcing a separate statement to increment the map values
2. if you try to `splita` or `splitax` the `$Contig` field, there seems to be no way of convincing it that `000000000013` is a *decimal* rather than octal integer. Hence the ugly regex `sub`.

You could instead use the `step` verb to do the per-category counts:

```
$ mlr --pprint step -a counter -f Contig -g Contig then put '
    $Contig_counter = sub($Contig,"c_0*([0-9]+)","\1_" . $Contig_counter)
  ' then rename Contig_counter,Count_of_contig input
Contig         Count_of_contig
c_000000000002 2_1
c_000000000002 2_2
c_000000000002 2_3
c_000000000002 2_4
c_000000000003 3_1
c_000000000003 3_2
c_000000000003 3_3
c_000000000003 3_4
c_000000000008 8_1
c_000000000008 8_2
c_000000000013 13_1
c_000000000013 13_2
```

This would probably be the preferred approach in the absence of the requirement to prefix the values:

```
$ mlr --pprint step -a counter -f Contig -g Contig input
Contig         Contig_counter
c_000000000002 1
c_000000000002 2
c_000000000002 3
c_000000000002 4
c_000000000003 1
c_000000000003 2
c_000000000003 3
c_000000000003 4
c_000000000008 1
c_000000000008 2
c_000000000013 1
c_000000000013 2
```

Comment: Thank you steeldriver it is also a solution for the problem. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @Roland you're welcome - tbh I don't think it's an especially "good" solution, I really only posted it here so I can find it again if I need something similar in the future ;)